# typescript: how to check if an array does not contains a value from another array and return the missing value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following set of values

```
const Idsetvalues = [38,38,38,38,38,43,43,43];
const IdsetMaster = [38,43];
```

I want to check id Idsetvalues contains either 38 or 43 and if it does not, return the element that is missng
e.g :

```
const Idsetvalues = [38,38,38,38,38];
const IdsetMaster = [38,43];
```

this should return false then return 43 is missing in Idsetvalues

I did something like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < IdsetMaster.length; i++) {
        const error1 = Idsetvalues.some(id => IdsetMaster[i].indexOf(id) >= 0);
console.log(error1)
 }
```

I get true for 38 and false for 43 but how to print only the value that returned false? or any other way to get the required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let missing;
if(!IdsetMaster.every(n => Idsetvalues.includes(missing=n))){
    console.log(missing);
}
```

Comment: I needed and array for "missing" but that did the trick thanks. I combined both answers

Answer (score 3):

You can always use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

```
IdsetMaster.filter(v => !Idsetvalues.includes(v))
```

This will return an array (it will not modify `IdsetMaster`) that contains every element in `IdsetMaster` that is not found in `Idsetvalues`.

Comment: yah that solves one par of my problem as it allows me to get the missing values perfectly.. but I still need to return false when 1 element of Idsetvalues does not contain 1 element of IdsetMaster

Comment: You can store that array to a variable and check if the length is greater than 0.

Comment: right, got it.. thank you so much I appreciate your help